python in excel 365 xl keyerror
I am discovering the new py function to use python in excel formulas.
I have a connection named "con" which return a table.
When I call this connection in python mode with xl('con') it works, but when I call xl(sCON), where sCON is a string variable containing 'con' as value, I get "keyerror".
Can I pass string for references through variables for xl()?
Thank you

same issue, any luck yet?
